# SQL Server - use a parameter to select the top X of the result set

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a SQL Server query that will take a parameter and use that as the record number to return.

In pseudo code:

```
parameter returnCount

select top returnCount * from table where x = y
```

What is the correct syntax/code to perform that operation?

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server are you using??

Comment: two year old question, and you SO storm troopers are just now marking it as a duplicate?!!

Comment: It's never too late

Comment: Yeah well google prefers this question to the others - top result in search for me. So it was helpful, relevant, and +1 to you sirs.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

In SqlServer 2005 and up, do this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetResults    (
    @ResultCount   int
)
AS

SELECT top(@ResultCount) FROM table where x = y
```

For earlier versions, use:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetResults    (
    @ResultCount   int
)
AS

SET ROWCOUNT @ResultCount

SELECT * FROM table where x = y
```

https://web.archive.org/web/20210417081325/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/070605-1.shtml for more information.

Comment: nice answer! thanks

Answer (score 25):

As of SQL Server 2005 (but not before that), you *can* define a variable to determine your number of TOP rows returned:

```
DECLARE @returnCount INT

SET @returnCount = 15

SELECT TOP (@returnCount) * 
FROM dbo.table 
WHERE x = y
```