# Are you able to pass the 'TOP' number as a parameter to a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server - use a parameter to select the top X of the result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285394/sql-server-use-a-parameter-to-select-the-top-x-of-the-result-set)

My query in my stored procedure looks something like:

```
select top 9 from my_table;
```

I'd like to edit the stored procedure to dynamically produce the limit from a parameter, however, this does not seem to be working:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_stored_procedure]
   @n INT(2)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT TOP @n from my_table;
```

Is this doable? Or do I have to do something like:

```
@n int(2),
@sql varchar(30)

@sql = 'select top ' + @n '* from my table';
exec(@sql);
```

Thanks.

Comment: what if you try `SELECT TOP(@n)`?

Comment: Just try it!  It would have been faster to actually run the query than to post it here.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-us?query=top&x=0&y=0

Comment: @onedaywhen You are correct, this is basically the same question. Thanks for pointing this out. I don't know the 'rules' regarding this situation. Mod delete this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You have to enclose the parameter in parenthesis like:

```
DECLARE @QQ INT = 10

SELECT  TOP (@QQ)
        *

FROM    Your_Table
```