# How to define a limit as parameter?

Tags: c#, t-sql, odbc

Given `conn` is an `OdbcConnection` object and `count` is an `int`, how would I use count as parameter for my query?

```
...
var query = conn.CreateCommand();
query.CommandText = "select top ? * from players order by Points desc";
query.Parameters.Add("top", OdbcType.Int).Value = count;

var reader = query.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    ...
}
...
```

This way I get a syntax error `ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'.`

If it is not possible the way I tried how would I do it the correct way instead?

Comment: couldn't you concatenate string for commandText?

Comment: top isn't the parameter, you should have something like `@Counter` in your query and add that as a parameter. I.e. `query.Parameters.Add("@Counter", OdbcType.Int).Value = count`

Comment: @user2525463 - you shouldn't concatenate strings, using parameters for queries is the correct way as it prevents SQL Injection.

Comment: @DarrenDavies i know top is not the parameter but how would I name a parameter as count for top?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server - use a parameter to select the top X of the result set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285394/sql-server-use-a-parameter-to-select-the-top-x-of-the-result-set)

Comment: @matthiaskrull, any particular reason that you are using `OdbcConnection` and now `SqlConnection` ??

Comment: @Habib No, I was using odbc with other languages and just looked it up. I am just doing quick and dirty experimenting and could switch to something else as well at this point.

Comment: @maf748 not a duplicate since the question asks specifically how to get that behaviour with `ODBC` which is different from `SqlConnection` for example and is not necessarily the same as raw `T-SQL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use SET ROWCOUNT the advantage is you can use a integer as parameter and avoid  dynamic queries.

```
SET ROWCOUNT @top;

select * from table;

SET ROWCOUNT 0;
```

read the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
query.CommandText = "select top (@topparameter) * from players order by Points desc";
query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@topparameter", count.ToString());
```

If you are using `SqlServer` then use `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` like:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
{
    using (SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("select top (@topparameter) * from players order by Points desc", conn))
    {
        query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@topparameter", count.ToString());
        var reader = query.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This yields `ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@topparameter"`.

Comment: @matthiaskrull, modified my answer with respect to SQL server, see if it works now.

Comment: T-SQL top command don't accepts a variable as parameter, you can do that way if you use a dynamic query. To avoid dynamic queries use set rowcount, se my answer below.

Comment: Using `SqlConnection` it works passing parameters this way. Thank you for your answer.